# How to combine the jquery UI slider with the jqueryrotate plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have someone who wants to be able to rotate an image without a handle. I figured that the best way to do this is using the UI slider. Is there a way to make the slider rotate the image 360 degrees using a UI slider.

in the fiddle is an example binding the click event to  the image. The click function rotates the image.  I want the uI slider to able to do this. Someone please help thanks.

`'$("#slider").slider({
        value: 90,
        max: 1000,
        min: 90,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
                        value +=90;
 $("img.resize-image").rotate({ animateTo:value});}});`
http://jsfiddle.net/kt7z8jaf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use the jquery rotate?
This works for me:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    max: 360,
    min: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {

        $("#image").css({
          '-webkit-transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
          '-moz-transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
          '-o-transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
          'transform': 'rotateZ('+ui.value+'deg)',
        })
```

}
});

http://jsfiddle.net/kt7z8jaf/1/

Note: I had to include the whole jquery ui thing in the js because it didn't load properly, but you only need the part I pasted here.

Comment: thanks Jonas this is exactly what I wanted to do I appreciate your help buddy.